# Antenna Matching 2.4GHz

Tags: antenna, impedance-matching

i'm using a 2,4GHz transceiver with a differential output. A Balun with 50Ω Output is connected. I have 3 free places to add matching Components in π Topology.

The antenna is placed on the other side of the PCB connected to a Via where i tried to match 50Ohm. The Antenna also has 50 Ohm.

I have a SignalHound Tracking Generator and SignalHound Spectrum Analyser.

I Recorded the folowing Diagramms for the Reflection.

I got the best Result with the last SetUp. Do you have any idea how to improve the process of matching. I'm not able to measure the SmithChart.

Greets,
Andi

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the antenna supplier recommend?

Comment: Define what needs to be improved. I (think I) see an S11 with a -40 dip, that is quite good. Maybe you want a wider bandwidth ? As far as I know you do what most RF designers do, try different values for the components and see what you get. You do not need to measure the Smith Chart separately, the Network Analyzer (software) should have an option for that. It is the same data presented in a different way. I also use S11 for matching, others might prefer the Smith Chart.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. It's a Molex 47948-0001 they only say how the "resonant frequency can be shifted up by 10 MHz with a 1pF in parallel and then 2.2 nH in series.

@FakeMoustache i also think -40dB looks good but they should be centered at 2.457 Ghz at the moment they are at 2.437 GhZ so 20 MHz to low. Does anyone have a suggestion to shift them up by 20Mhz with my given Setup

Comment: What a weird antenna ! Did not know these existed. 20 MHz on 2.4 GHz that is only about 1% so you're quite close. The only solution I see is, like I said, try different component values to find a better combination. This is the RF black art ;-)

Comment: Yes i needed an Antenna which can be placed on a Ground plane.

Okay so from what i posted there is no way to roughly calculate the needed values to get closer to 2457 MHz? Or any suggestion with which values i can shift the frequency up from my last example?